# Combining custom comparison with key selection in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sorting

I'm migrating a bunch of python 2.7 code to python 3 which has patterns like this in python 2.7:

```
sorted(some_list, cmp=custom_compare, key=custom_key_getter)
```

The best way I could figure out to migrate this was as follows:

```
sorted(some_list, 
       key=functools.cmp_to_key(
             lambda x,y: custom_compare(custom_key_getter(x), 
                                        custom_key_getter(y)))
```

Is there a better way? Or a more idiomatic way that conforms to python 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a stopgap solution, I think it's fine.

If you have several combinations of `custom_compare` and `custom_key_getter`, I'd factor out the lambda as

```
def compare_using(custom_compare, custom_key_getter):
   def comparator(x, y):
     return custom_compare(custom_key_getter(x), custom_key_getter(y))
   return comparator
```

If you have only a few combinations, I can imagine making them pre-computed, e.g.

```
compare_names_special = compare_using(compare_special, itemgetter('name'))
...
customers_by_name = sorted(customers, compare_names_special)
```

Performance should not be affected, because this code just surfaces what Python 2's sorting did under wraps anyway.

In longer term, I'd consider rewriting the custom compare functions so that they don't need `cmp_to_key` handling; in most cases it should be trivial.